How to Stubbing Azure Client Using Mocha and chai
const { EventHubConsumerClient, earliestEventPosition } = require("@azure/event-hubs");
const { ContainerClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const { BlobCheckpointStore } = require("@azure/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob");
const FIGmdLogger = require(process.cwd() + "/utility/logger").logger;
const secretManagerConfig = require(process.cwd() + '/utility/secretmanagerhandler');
const secretValue = secretManagerConfig.secretValue;
const { publisher } = require(process.cwd() + "/publisher/publisherbusiness");
const moment = require('moment');
 /* main function sets up the Event Hub consumer, processes filtered events, publishes messages to Google Pub/Sub, 
   updates checkpoints, and logs events and errors.
 */
async function main() {
  try {
    // Create a blob container client to interact with the Azure Blob container.
    const containerClient = new ContainerClient(secretValue?.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING, secretValue?.AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME);

    // Initialize a blob checkpoint store using the container client for event checkpointing. 
    const checkpointStore = new BlobCheckpointStore(containerClient);

    // Create a consumer client for the event hub by specifying the checkpoint store.
    const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(secretValue?.AZURE_EV_CONSUMER_GROUP, secretValue?.AZURE_EH_CONNECTION_STRING, process.env.AZURE_EVENT_HUB_NAME, checkpointStore);

    // Subscribe to the events, and specify handlers for processing the events and errors.
    consumerClient.subscribe({
      processEvents: async (aevents, context) => {

        if (events.length === 0) {
          FIGmdLogger.info("ReceiveEvent processEvents:No events received within wait time. Waiting for next interval.");
          return;
        }
      // Filter events based on subscription key and ensure EventName is 'TaskCompleted' and Status is 'completed'
        const filteredEvents = events.filter((event) => (event?.body?.SubscriptionKey === secretValue?.CDXP_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY) && (event?.body?.EventName.toLowerCase() === process?.env?.CDXP_READY_FOR_DOWNLOAD_EVENT_NAME) && (event?.body?.Status.toLowerCase() === process.env.CDXP_COMPETED_EVENT_STATUS));

   
        const lastEvent = events[events.length - 1];
        await context.updateCheckpoint(lastEvent);
        FIGmdLogger.info(`ReceiveEvent processEvents:Checkpoint updated for partition: '${context.partitionId}'`, { eventId: lastEvent?.body?.EventId, taskId: lastEvent?.body?.TaskId, subscriptionKey: lastEvent?.body?.SubscriptionKey, eventName: lastEvent?.body?.EventName, eventStatus: lastEvent?.body?.Status });
      },

      processError: async (err, context) => {
        FIGmdLogger.error(`ReceiveEvent processError:Error processing events from partition: '${context.partitionId}. Error: ${err.message}`, { consumerGroup: context.consumerGroup, partitionId: context.partitionId, errorMessage: err.message, errStack: err.stack });
      }
    },
    // Configure the consumer to start from the earliest event position and set the maximum batch size for event processing.
      { startPosition: earliestEventPosition, maxBatchSize: process.env.MAX_BATCH_SIZE }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  const { message, stack } = err;
  FIGmdLogger.error(`ReceiveEvent error occurred: ${message}`, { stackTrace: stack });
});`your text`

I need to write unit tests for the provided code using Mocha, Chai, and Sinon. Could you please help me? Below are the scenarios that need to be tested:

Container Client Connection
Verify that the container client connects with the given credentials (AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING, AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME).

Blob Checkpoint Store Connection
Check if the Azure Blob checkpoint store is connected with the received containerClient.

EventHubConsumerClient Connection
Ensure that the EventHubConsumerClient connects with the provided credentials (AZURE_EV_CONSUMER_GROUP, AZURE_EH_CONNECTION_STRING, AZURE_EVENT_HUB_NAME) and the checkpointStore.

ConsumerClient Subscribe Method
Test if the subscribe method of the consumer client works as expected.

processEvents Method
Verify that the processEvents method functions correctly when events are received.

processError Method
Ensure that the processError method works properly when an error occurs.

Event Filtering
Confirm that the event filtering mechanism is working as intended.

Ignore Logs
You can ignore testing the logs.


